# List of object attributes in pydantic model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I use Fast API to create a web service.

There are following sqlAlchemy models:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    account_name = Column(String, primary_key=True, index=True, unique=True)
    email = Column(String, unique=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    roles = relationship("UserRole", back_populates="users", lazy=False, uselist=True)


class UserRole(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user_role'
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint('role_name', 'user_name', name='user_role_uc'),)
    role_name = Column(String, ForeignKey('role.name'), primary_key=True)
    user_name = Column(String, ForeignKey('user.account_name'), primary_key=True)
    users = relationship("User", back_populates="roles")
```

Pydantic schemas are below:

```
class UserRole(BaseModel):
    role_name: str

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


class UserBase(BaseModel):
    account_name: str
    email: EmailStr
    roles: List[UserRole] = []

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

What I have now is:

```
{
  "account_name": "Test.Test",
  "email": "Test.Test@test.com",
  "roles": [
    {
      "role_name": "all:admin"
    },
    {
      "role_name": "all:read"
    }
  ]
}
```

What I want to achieve is to get user from api in following structure:

```
{
  "account_name": "Test.Test",
  "email": "Test.Test@test.com",
  "roles": [
    "all:admin",
    "all:read"
  ]
}
```

Is that possible? How should I change schemas to get this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use nested pydantic models for sqlalchemy in a flexible way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64414030/how-to-use-nested-pydantic-models-for-sqlalchemy-in-a-flexible-way)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are okay
with handling the how to "get user from api" problem statement
by modifying the fastapi path definition, see below.

Can you change the response model used by the fastapi path definition
in order to handle the desired output format?

Example pydantic response model definition:

```py
class UserResponse(BaseModel):
    account_name: str
    email: EmailStr
    roles: List[str]
```

Example sqlalchemy query + serialization function:

```py
def get_user_response(user_id) -> UserResponse:
    user = User.query.get(user_id)
    user_roles = UserRole.query.filter(user=user_id).all()
    role_names = [r.role_name for r in user_roles]
    response = UserResponse(
        account_name=user.account_name,
        email=user.email,
        roles=role_names
    }
    return response
```

Example fastapi path definition:

```py
@app.get("/users/{user_id}", response_model=UserResponse)
async def read_item(user_id):
    return get_user_response(user_id)
```

Considerations:

- I'm using a `user_id` for the user queries but this can be replaced with whatever you end up using as your primary key for that table.
- The `UserResponse` response model is very similar to `UserBase` (you could potentially
  subclass `UserBase` instead of model to avoid the redefinition of
  `account_name` and `email`, with the tradeoff of having to override the
  class' `Config`).
- There may be a way to override the serialization format of the `UserBase`
  sqlalchemy model object that gets automatically serialized when you query the model from the database
  and allows you to eliminate or reduce the code in the `get_user_response()` function in the example definition above.

Answer (score 0):

As UserRole is a class, it is represented as an object (using a dictionary). If you want to represent it as a list of strings you'll have to transform the data (and change your Pydantic model's field declaration). There's several approaches to this, but the pydantic model [documentation](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/) is a good place to start. Mind that the ORM model serves as the data representation layer and the pydantic model is the validation (and perhaps serialization) layer, so there's a lot of places where you could 'hook in'.