# AttributeError: 'BaseModel' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I have the following code in my app:

> models.py

```
class MainTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = "main_table"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    owner = Column(String, index=True)

    metas = relationship("ChildTable", back_populates="item")

class ChildTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = "child"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    segment = Column(Integer)
    name = Column(String)
    main_name = Column(String, ForeignKey('main_table.name'), nullable=False)
    item = relationship("MainTable", back_populates="metas")
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint('segment', 'main_name', name='_meta_for_main'),
                      )
```

And when I run my app, and create new obj in db:

```
{
  "name": "string",
  "owner": "string",
  "metas": [
     {
      "segment": 0,
      "name": "string",
      "main_name": "string",
    }
   ]
}
```

I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'MainMetaCreate' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'

> schemas.py

```
class EnvironmentMetaBase(BaseModel):
    segment: int
    name: str
    main_name: str
```

Haw you met the following problem?

Comment: What is `MainMetaCreate` ? and how do you create your new obj in the db ?

Comment: found the answer in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64414030/how-to-use-nested-pydantic-models-for-sqlalchemy-in-a-flexible-way

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use nested pydantic models for sqlalchemy in a flexible way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64414030/how-to-use-nested-pydantic-models-for-sqlalchemy-in-a-flexible-way)